# Nodejs Express - dynamicHelpers error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to run my app with the following:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.enable('jsonp callback');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', {layout : false});
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret : 'abcdefg'      
  }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

});

app.dynamicHelpers({
  session : function(req, res){
    return req.session;
  }
});
```

And getting the following error message when running `node app.js`

```
app.dynamicHelpers({

TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'dynamicHelpers'
    at Object.<annonymous> (C:\nodeapps\nodeblox\app.js:35:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.Load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallBack (node.js:244:9)
```

Im kind of new to using nodejs but I understand that dynamicHelpers() is no longer supported with Express, I have tried re-working the code and continue to get errors all over the place. What is the correct way to fix this dynamicHelpers code so that it ensures the rest of the code is still working correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you are not using Express 2 but Express 3. There is [migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) that helps you figure out what happened. For dynamicHelpers() you need to understanding that the app.use function needs to be IN the configure part, not where it was before.

**Before**

```
app.configure();
app.dynamicHelpers({
  user: function(req, res) {
    return req.session.user;
  }
});
```

**Now in E3**

```
app.configure(function(){
  //...
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.session.user;
    next();
  });
  //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you propose I do here in my view where I have written `- if(session.user)` I want to show they are a logged in label if they are logged in, which I can't check now as I did with dynamicHelpers. What would you suggest to replace such a thing?

Comment: to my knowledge you now need to use the session itself to register if the user has logged on. Usually I'd do that with a cookieParser() if you are fond of cookies.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I'm getting `session is not defined` wherever I have `session.*.*` written, could you link an example of this or explain what you said at all? I'm new to using express/nodejs, I understood all the concepts of the code but I'm not too familiar with certain features sorry!

Comment: i see you've opened another question to this problem. please make sure you accept answers if they were correct, so others can see if the solution was the right one.

Comment: Sorry about that forgot to do so, I've opened another question as I didn't expect you to answer to a comment. Thanks for your help and if you could help I'd appreciate the help on the other question. Accepted the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
**In Epress3.x** there seems to be having no concept of static or dynamic.
use global or local instead.

/*Global*/
app.locals({ foo: 'bar' });
//or
app.locals.foo = 'bar';

/*For single request*/
res.locals({ foo: 'bar' });
//or
res.locals.foo = 'bar';
```

**more** difference refers [Here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).